# Mounting a Windows Share into Kubernetes pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, containers, windows-share

We are migrating some windows components (.net 4.5) to Linux containers (.net core). Existing system is a file processor, which watches a shared location and processes file from there. We can't force existing system to start dropping file at some other location, so new containerised application has to access from same shared location. Can a windows share be seen from docker containers? If yes, then how can I use Kubernete deployment file to achieve it?
Please advise.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not working by default, but yes, you can do this. [Here is the project](https://github.com/juliohm1978/kubernetes-cifs-volumedriver) which allows you to do this in a proper way. After volume driver setup, you can use  Windows share as [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) in your Kubernetes cluster.

***Updates**

Also you can use windows share as nfs volume in Kubernetes. [Here you](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs) can find some examples of using nfs in Kubernetes